# android playing mp3 files from raw folder or from asset folder when more than 100 mp3 files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am creating 1 app that containing .mp3 playing functionality... my question is.. what is good to put my mp3 files in raw folder or to put files into assets folder? i have approx 100 mp3.

Right now i have puted that files in to raw folder.. it worked for 20 30 files but after 70 it says me `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE` so what is better? is it problem remain same with asset folder also? it containing too much time to load
can anybody help me to find out the best solution?

Comment: How much space do the 100 mp3 files occupy? Is this happening while trying to install in the emulator or device?

Comment: Please do not add *random* formatting to ***words*** that you think are **important**.  It makes your posts hard to read.  Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (raw, asset, mp3, playback) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need supply this songs which your app use [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) to do so. You songs will be download right after your app and then will be accessable.